# Changing titles on big cartel

Tags: bigcartel

Can any one help with changing the default titles such as Product, products, categories?

I would like to change these to art works and collections however not knowledgeable on where and what to change in the code.

Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Tried to locate the area in home & products